# Why modal in bootstrap is not covering the whole area?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to open a modal for form fill up in Vue.Js using Bootstrap, but the modal content is not covering the whole modal, just a small part.

I have also used Google's Materialize CSS with Boostrap (for reasons), and have tried removing the Materialize CSS cdns but the problem is something else.
[image]

Code for modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1"   aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog"  >
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
              <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" v-model="title">
          </div>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <!-- <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" v-model="title">
          </div> -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Content:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" v-model="content" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="saveChanges()">Save Note</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i did not style it 
but the order in which cdns for boostrap and materilize css

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Semi+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/vue-cookie/build/vue-cookie.js'"></script>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML & CSS otherwise it is very difficult to offer any help.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: It would be helpful if you make a working snippet

Comment: don't know howb to make it .ps googling also did not help me about snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is Materialize CSS..  This line: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">`

[[CodePen Mirror]](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/agvmZg?editors=1010)

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Semi+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1"  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
              <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" v-model="title">
          </div>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <!-- <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" v-model="title">
          </div> -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Content:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" v-model="content" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="saveChanges()">Save Note</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```